# Optimising Pandas multi-index lookup

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I Use Pandas 0.12.0. Say `multi_df` is a Pandas dataframe with multiple index. And I have a (long) list of tuples (multiple indexes), named `look_up_list`. I want to perform an operation if a tuple in `look_up_list` is in `multi_df`.

Below is my code. **Is there a faster way to achieve this?** In reality `len(multi_df)`and `len(look_up_list)` are quite large so I need to **optimise** this line: `[multi_df.ix[idx]**2 for idx in look_up_list if idx in multi_df.index]`.

In particular, [line_profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) tells me that the contidional check: `if idx in multi_df.index` takes a long time.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                    'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                    'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                            'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                    'texture': ['soft', 'soft', 'hard','soft','hard',
                                        'hard','hard','hard'],
                    'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                        'triangular','round','triangular']
                    },  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'texture', 'shape'])
multi_df = df.set_index(['code','colour','texture','shape']).sort_index()['id']

# define the list of indices that I want to look up for in multi_df
look_up_list = [('two', 'white', 'hard', 'triangular'),('five', 'black', 'hard', 'square'),('four', 'black', 'hard', 'round') ] 
# run a list comprehension
[multi_df.ix[idx]**2 for idx in look_up_list if idx in multi_df.index]
```

P.S: The actual operation in the list comprehension is not `multi_df.ix[idx]**2`, but something like: `a_slow_function(multi_df.ix[idx])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use `multi_df.loc[look_up_list].dropna()`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': range(1, 9),
     'code': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
              'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
     'colour': ['black', 'white', 'white', 'white',
                'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
     'texture': ['soft', 'soft', 'hard', 'soft', 'hard',
                 'hard', 'hard', 'hard'],
     'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular', 'triangular', 'square',
               'triangular', 'round', 'triangular']
     }, columns=['id', 'code', 'colour', 'texture', 'shape'])
multi_df = df.set_index(
    ['code', 'colour', 'texture', 'shape']).sort_index()['id']

# define the list of indices that I want to look up for in multi_df
look_up_list = [('two', 'white', 'hard', 'triangular'), (
    'five', 'black', 'hard', 'square'), ('four', 'black', 'hard', 'round')]

subdf = multi_df.loc[look_up_list].dropna()
print(subdf ** 2)
```

yields

```
(two, white, hard, triangular)     9
(two, white, hard, triangular)    64
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

Note:

- `multi_df` as defined above is a Series, not a DataFrame. I don't
  think that affects the solution though.
- The code you posted above raises `IndexingError: Too many indexers`
  so I'm guessing (a little bit) at the intention of the code.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu. I do not get the `IndexingError: Too many indexers` error when I run the code I gave in the question. Strange...

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using? (I'm using v0.13.1.) This might be a regression.

Comment: I use 0.12.0 (added to the question as well). (I am trying to apply your solution and compare times.)

Comment: Ok, I installed 0.12.0 and no longer think this is a regression. If you print out `idx in multi_df.index` for each `idx in look_up_list`, you'll see it is always `True`. So that condition isn't doing what it's intended to do. In v0.12.0, `multi_df.ix[idx]` returns `Series([], dtype: int64)` when `idx` is "missing", but in `v0.13.1`, it raises an `IndexingError`.

Comment: Thanks unutbu: 1) I checked and agree that `idx in multi_df.index` does not act as intended, I changed it to `idx in multi_df.index.tolist()` which works but I am not sure whether `tolist()` reduces performance? 2)The thing that puzzles me with your comment is how `idx` can ever be missing while making the calls like `multi_df.ix[idx] for idx in look_up_list`?

Comment: Checking membership in a list is an `O(n)` operation. Checking membership in a set is a `O(1)` operation. So using a set would be better than a list. However using the indexer itself should be even better than converting to and checking membership with a Python set. After all, finding matching labels is its reason for being. Re: 2), all I meant was when `idx` equals a tuple like `('four', 'black', 'hard', 'round')`, which does not match a row in `multi_df.index` (i.e. "missing"), then `v0.13.1` raises an IndexError.

Comment: I see, is it a bug that `idx in multi_df.index` does not work as intended? As you said: "using the indexer itself should be even better since finding matching labels is its reason for being". It feels wrong to have to convert it to anything.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bug, but it is definitely not right for this purpose, and I do think it is better to stick with the indexers, `loc`, `iloc` or `ix` when possible.

Comment: using ``[ i in multi_df.index for i in look_up_list ]`` will always succeed but can return 0-len indexers. This is not a public method, e.g. its doing ``multi_df.index.get_loc(i)`` under the hood.

Comment: @Jeff, thank you. Just briefly: is the fastest way to check whether an index value (e.g. the first tuple in look_up_list) exists in a dataframe: `look_up_list[0] in multi_df.index` ?

Comment: just try to select it via loc